# I have started getting "error -1=ffffffffffffffff Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1" in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode9.1

Everything was working fine and all of a sudden I started getting below error in Xcode while building the project. I have not seen such errors before. And checked the certificates and profile all looks file. Not sure why its occurring.

```
error -1=ffffffffffffffff Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Updated the developer account certificate and resign again from preference s section for developer account and restarted the system and it got fixed. It helped me fix the issue.

Comment: I get this error when manually codesigning App bundles if the bundle contains files with extended attributes (e.g. quarantine bits).

Comment: @mschmidt can you please provide me the link to reproduce this issue. I want to reproduce to know the exact problem.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no link, it was just a problem I encountered once.

Answer (score 2):

Try updating your keyChain password. For that try following

If you don't know your old password, the solution is to create a new login keychain.
If you know your old password, use that password to update your existing login keychain:
Open the Keychain Access app, which is in the the Utilities folder of your Applications folder.
From the list of keychains on the left side of the window, select "login."
From the Edit menu in the menu bar, choose “Change Password for Keychain 'login.'”
Enter the old password of your user account in the Current Password field.
This is the password you were using before the password was reset.
Enter the new password of your user account in the New Password field. This is the password you're now using to log in to your Mac. Enter the same password in the Verify field.
Click OK when done, then quit Keychain Access. Quit your Xcode, reopen the project and try building your project it should work.